# Angularjs $http post doesnt binding with asp.net web api server model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, rest

I have next problem:
Angularjs $http post request dont binding body attributes  with model on server side. Model created but with null properties. 
I have tested with Chrome Postman and firefox poster. All works and binding. So problem supposed to be in angullar

```
 local.signup = function(user) {
      $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      return $http.post(config.signupUrl, {displayName:user.displayName,email:user.email, password: user.password})
        .then(function(response) {
          if (config.loginOnSignup) {
            shared.setToken(response);
          } else if (config.signupRedirect) {
            $location.path(config.signupRedirect);
          }
          return response;
        });
    };
```

and server side controller method

```
    [HttpOptions]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("signup")]
    public IHttpActionResult Signup([FromBody] User model)
    {
        if (model == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.email))
            return BadRequest("Email Address is required.");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.displayName))
            return BadRequest("Name is required.");
            ......
         }
```

**EDIT**
User model

```
    public class User
{

    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `User` class structure?

Comment: @OmriAharon yes, of course. I have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer!
First of all, there can be used jObject like

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] jObject model){..}
```

but then I dissappeared other problem - jObject model was with backaslashes and angular POST request turn into OPTIONS request. The reason was in [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
Deeping in, I found solution in Thinktecture.dll which allow CORS. Futher information for configuration you can found in next article [CORS support in WebAPI, MVC and IIS](http://brockallen.com/2012/06/28/cors-support-in-webapi-mvc-and-iis-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/).
And after that, all working! 
Good luck!